# How to pass arguments in generic delegate?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to pass arguments in generic delegate????

**NoOfRecords = new DelegateCommand(number);**

in the code above i want to pass argument in **number** ex:number(23)??

Please give me your valuable suggesions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `DelegateCommand`?  A class or a delegate type?  Where's the generic?

Comment: What is that `DelegateCommand`? What is `number` here? If this is the [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654312.aspx) you're using, then you need to pass `Action<T>` to the constructor. It's not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below,

```
    public DelegateCommand<int> NoOfRecords { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        NoOfRecords = new DelegateCommand<int>(Number);
    }

    private void Number(int value)
    {
        // Do your logic
    }
```

Comment: I think if you actually invoke the `NoOfRecords` delegate value, passing `23` to it, you _might_ actually have answered this question. (Or you might not...the question itself is very poorly expressed).

Comment: I'm doing this in this way only ,,,,thankss

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
void Main()
{
    var NoOfRecords = new DelegateCommand(number);

    NoOfRecords(23);
}

public delegate void DelegateCommand(int x);

public void number(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```